# Google maps query results from sql wth asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, google-maps-api-3

I couldn’t find any resurce for how to use a DB query (sql) and display all the results on a map while all I have is the address ,
 I have about 12, 000 results that all I have is the street name & number + city name,
I can get a single result each time, I need to get much more then that

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var model = await db.synagogues.Take(5).ToListAsync();
    return View(model.ToList());
}
```

and get the map results by `foreach` .

```
function codeAddress() {

        var address = document.getElementById('address' + i).value;
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
            } else {
                alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
            }
        });

}

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Can you show your javascript code, How are you trying to get results?

Comment: how are you calling `codeAddress`?

Comment: <input type="button" value="Geocode" onclick="codeAddress()">